# Error printing variables while debugging Cython

Tags: python, gdb, cython, pdb, gdb-python

I'm trying to debug some Cython code with gdb that is wrapping C++ code to be called from Python. I followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/debugging.html) but I'm getting some errors while debugging that are unrelated to my code. Example:

```
(gdb) cy print some_variable
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'PyDictObjectPtr' object has no attribute 'items':
Error occurred in Python: 'PyDictObjectPtr' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I'm also getting this one sometimes (usually after the first one):

```
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named ob_sval.:
Error occurred in Python command: There is no member named ob_sval.
```

To debug the code I created an environment with Docker:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential gdb-python2 python-dbg python-dev \
  python-pip python-numpy-dbg

RUN pip install cython pygments

CMD bash
```

I found two [related](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cython-users/$27PyDictObjectPtr$27$20object$20has$20no$20attribute$20$27items$27%7Csort:date/cython-users/SCk2IDG9M5g/muhUhmw9AwAJ) [posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cython-users/$27PyDictObjectPtr$27$20object$20has$20no$20attribute$20$27items$27%7Csort:date/cython-users/igbIwwwTWUg/vxp5EXz1BwAJ) in the cython-users google group but with no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An issue was finally opened in Cython (thanks @hygorxaraujo!) and it was identified as a defect:

https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2699

Pull requests welcome!